# How to run PipelineModel SageMaker at the local

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Can we create a PipelineModel and run a batch transform at the local?
I don't see any document about this. I tried but get the error

```
sagemaker_session = LocalSession()
sagemaker_session.config = {'local': {'local_code': True}}
model_1 = PyTorchModel(...)
model_2 = PyTorchModel(...)
model = PipelineModel(models=[model_1, model_2])
transformer = model.transformer(...)
transformer.transform(...)

self.sagemaker_client.create_model(**create_model_request)
TypeError: create_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'PrimaryContainer'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's still a feature request:

https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/1846